# Unable to access process variable in Vue3JS Vite project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web3js, vite, ipfs

I am creating a vue3 application (created with Vite) that interacts with a smart contract written in Solidity and stored on Ropsten. Therefore I am using web3js to interact with my smart contracts and also web3.storage in order to store some images on IPFS. I have a `.env` file at the root of my project storing my API key for web3.storage :

```
VUE_APP_API_TOKEN=VALUE
VITE_API_TOKEN=VALUE
```

The problem is that apparently web3.storage expects the API token to be stored in process.env and I am unable to access the global `process` variable from my application. I am always getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

I think, this is linked to my usage of Vite instead of pure Vue3.
I tried to export process env in the `vite.config.ts` file with that code but it didn't work:

```
export default ({ mode }) => {
   process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '') };

   console.log(process.env.VITE_API_TOKEN)         //Works fine: VALUE is logged
   console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_API_TOKEN)      //Works fine: VALUE is logged

   return defineConfig({
       plugins: [vue()]
   });
}
```

How could I access the `process` variable from my vue files in order to get the values of my environment variable and make web3.storage work?

Comment: [Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) might help.

Comment: @tao thanks for the tip, I already tried with the documentation but it didn't help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***.env***

```
VITE_WEB3_STORAGE_TOKEN="your_token"
```

***SomeComponent.vue:*** (or any other file of your app, really):

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_WEB3_STORAGE_TOKEN) // "your_token"
```

---

**Note**: as specified in [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files), only variables prefixed with `VITE_` will be exposed:

> To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with `VITE_` are exposed to your Vite-processed code.

Comment: Okay thank you for your solution, I feel like this is the only way. The "process" global variable doesn't seem to be accessible anymore in Vue3 projects

Comment: It's not, for precisely the reason quoted in my answer. Considering what `process` has access to, and what people tend to put in those environment variables, I personally think it's a sensible only to expose what's been prefixed with `VITE`. You can now safely use other names for stuff that should not be visible anywhere in the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the build script in CI you will need to make sure that you're creating / populating the relevant `.env` file before you run the build script.