# VUE 3 - process.env ALWAYS returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, undefined, vue-cli

I am trying to access env variables using a .env file in a VueJS 3 project, following the docs of vue 3 and some issues over here, but nothing seems to work.

I already checked, the .env is inside the root, i've already stoped and re-runned the project hundreds of times, rebuilt, everthing, and i'M STILL GETTING unfefined on this shit, and i found out always the same tips, and lot of people complaining about this feature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is returning from console.log(process.env) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access process variable in Vue3JS Vite project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104342/unable-to-access-process-variable-in-vue3js-vite-project)

Answer (score 5):

If you use Vue3 + Vite, you must type the good syntax. In your .env file rather then VUE_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN change it to `VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Then restart your app.

Now in your **components/pages** you can access it via:
`import.meta.env.VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN`

example:

```
<script setup>
const accessToken = import.meta.env.VITE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You the goat, this was by far the only online solution that worked! Saved me from a project, there should be documentation that says this. Thank you so much for this!