# .env variables work in development, not in production (using Vite + React)

Tags: reactjs, vite, .env

I am using Vite + React for a personal project. In development, the VITE_PUBLIC_KEY works and can be logged in the console. I do not want this key and two others (formatted similarly) to be visible to anyone. I have them in a .env file as:

```
VITE_SERVICE_ID="some key"
VITE_TEMPLATE_ID="some key"
VITE_PUBLIC_KEY="some key"
```

My vite.config.js is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config();

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/blakes-portfolio/' : '/',
  define: {
    __PUBLIC_KEY__: `"${process.env.VITE_PUBLIC_KEY}"`,
    __SERVICE_ID__: `"${process.env.VITE_SERVICE_ID}"`,
    __TEMPLATE_ID__: `"${process.env.VITE_TEMPLATE_ID}"`
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3000,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```

the function used is:

```
export default function ContactMe() {
    const form = useRef();
    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(form.current);
        const userName = formData.get('user_name');
        const userEmail = formData.get('user_email');
        const userMessage = formData.get('user_message');

        if (!userName || !userEmail || !userMessage) {
            alert('Please fill out all fields');
            return;
        }

        const serviceID = `${__SERVICE_ID__}`
        const templateID = `${__TEMPLATE_ID__}`
        const publicKey = `${__PUBLIC_KEY__}`

        console.log(publicKey)


        emailjs.sendForm(serviceID, templateID, form.current, publicKey)

        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
            form.current.reset()
            alert('Message sent successfully!')
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
    }
```

I am out of ideas. I can see the key in development, however in production it is just "undefined".
Am I missing anything? Through extensive research with documentation I still have not come to a solution.

The .env file is in the root folder:

```
- ghi
| - dist
| - node_modules
| - src (and the rest of ghi files)
-.env
-.gitignore
-.gitlab-ci.yml
- docker-compose.yaml
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access process variable in Vue3JS Vite project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104342/unable-to-access-process-variable-in-vue3js-vite-project)